# VB.NET - Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am new to VB.NET.  I can execute the following stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Declare @iResult int
Declare @sMessage VarChar(100)

Exec [WebSite].[vwWebCustomerPasswordUpdate] 'BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E', 'EF80AF910FA07870E25B1A4C86D10402', @iResult output, @sMessage output

Print @iResult
Print @sMessage
```

Now, I want to execute the stored procedure from VB.NET.  I am writing this code, but it gives me the error "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid".  Here's the code that's failing:

```
Dim ssql As String
ssql = " Declare @iResult int Declare @sMessage VarChar(100) Exec [WebSite].[vwWebCustomerPasswordUpdate] 'BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E', 'EF80AF910FA07870E25B1A4C86D10402', @iResult output, @sMessage output"

Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open()

Dim Command As New SqlCommand(ssql, connection)
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Command.CommandText = "[WebSite].[vwWebCustomerPasswordUpdate]"
Command.Parameters.Add("@CustGUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
Command.Parameters("@CustGUID").Value = "BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E"
Command.Parameters.Add("@pWordHash", SqlDbType.VarChar)
Command.Parameters("@pWordHash").Value = "BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E"

Command.BeginExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Please show the full error too.

Comment: This is the error Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid.

Comment: You're calling your stored procedure `vw.....` - that seems to violate the *Principle of Least Surprise* - anyone who seems `vw` will assume it's a **view** ...

Comment: Another suggestion: if you have a parameter `VARCHAR(100)` in your stored procedure, I'd recommend to **always** specify that length in your VB.NET code, too! Change `Command.Parameters.Add("@pWordHash", SqlDbType.VarChar)` to `Command.Parameters.Add("@pWordHash", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)` to define that length. Otherwise, you might suddenly end up with a parameter of **1 character length** - which is most likely not what you want ...

Comment: Procedure or function 'vwWebCustomerPasswordUpdate' expects parameter '@iResult', which was not supplied. this is the error i am getting now

Comment: A hundred thousand thanks to all of you it is solved

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is

```
Command.Parameters("@CustGUID").Value = New Guid("BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E")
```

Comment: Please tick if answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Command.Parameters("@CustGUID").Value = 
      "BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E"
```

to

```
Command.Parameters("@CustGUID").Value = 
     New Guid("BF49F8B8-B580-4714-85F5-D87E4901009E");
```