# Error in VB.Net -- Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable, uniqueidentifier

I get a "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

I am using a String on the VB side and a GUID on the database side.....

Is there an equivalent field that I can use on the VB side that can work well with a "uniqueidentifier" data type in the Sql Server

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13428960/261997

Comment: A `uniqueidentifier` is a `GUID`.
 Apart from that, don't concatenate your query but use sql-parameters to prevent conversion or localization errors  and -more important- to prevent sql-injection.

Comment: How should I handle the empty string parmList.Add(String.Empty) when the table column is a GUID?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have your value as a string and since you are writing out your SQL by hand, you can `CONVERT` it like this:

```
strSql.Append("INSERT INTO tableName ")
strSql.Append("(GUID, ParentObsSetGUID, ChildObsSetGUID, ChildObsItemGUID) ")
strSql.Append(String.Format("VALUES (CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{0}'), CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{1}'), CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{2}'), CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{3}'))", parmList.ToArray))
```

**EDIT:** If you have an empty string and you need a new Guid, then do this:

```
parmList.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

instead of

```
parmList.Add(String.Empty)
```

If you would rather insert a `NULL` into the GUID column, then you need to change the last bit of your code to be like this instead:

```
parmList.Add(dtNewGUID.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
parmList.Add(dtResultParentGUID.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
parmList.Add(dtResultChildGUID.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString)
// remove the line with the empty string parameter
strSql.Append("INSERT INTO tableName ")
strSql.Append("(GUID, ParentObsSetGUID, ChildObsSetGUID, ChildObsItemGUID) ")
strSql.Append(String.Format("VALUES (CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{0}'), CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{1}'),
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '{2}'), NULL)", parmList.ToArray))
// Note the change to the last line. '{3}' becomes NULL.
// Make sure you remove the single quotes
```

**NOTE:** Your code as it stands (and this answer) is/are vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack, but that's another matter. At least with this answer you know how to convert the string to a `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: The following still gives me the same error:  INSERT INTO aic_obs_set_obs_set_obs_item_xref (GUID, ParentObsSetGUID, ChildObsSetGUID, ChildObsItemGUID) 
 VALUES (CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, 'a1771622-6cd6-49f7-8b26-6befafaf556e'), 
         CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '4746da06-e830-42a0-9761-ce60a62ea4d1'), 
   CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '633ce901-1d4d-479c-b295-232fe7b53295'), 
   CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, ''))